# atomic ops embedded, std::atomic understanding

Tags: c++, arm, embedded, atomic

If I have a shared var x which is accessed within an isr and a main loop.

```
int x;

void isr() {
     x++;
}

void loop() {
    y = x;
}
```

In the past, I would wrap the `loop` call with an atomic operation using assembly, i.e. `y = atomic_get(x)` . The `isr` increment would not change.

In reading about C++ atomics, it seems that I can make `x` an atomic type. The `y = x` would be handled atomically under the hood.

The `x` in the `isr`, when using atomics, would also want to do 'something' atomically, as it doesn't know it's within a thread that can't be interrupted. How does that work?

Is it guaranteed that the `x++` will always happen when the `isr` is called, and that `y` will always show a value of 'x' (not relevant if it's before or after a pending `x++`)?

Comment: You might want to look at atomic member function `fetch_add` which can safely do `x++`

Comment: @doug -- `x++` will safely do `x++`. The increment is atomic.

Comment: @PeteBecker Nice. I hadn't realized `++` was defined for atomic classes.

Comment: @doug — it’s defined for `atomic<integral-type>`, not for all `atomic<T>`. And I just noticed that the question doesn’t mention they type of `x`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I've never used `++` on an atomic type but have used `fetch_add` because I was updating a value with differing int qtys. So it came to mind when I saw `x++`  Not brave enough to try floating point Ts.

Comment: @doug -- floating-point types don't support `++`. `atomic<floating-type>` doesn't, either. It's just `atomic<integral-type>` that has the reflexive operations.

Comment: @PeteBecker I was referring to my frequent use of `fetch_add`, which c++20 now supports. Sort of.

Comment: Thanks Doug & Pete Becker. I added in a little more details as to what I'm concerned about. It seems that atomics ensure data is not corrupt however doesn't guarantee execution.. I'm not sure.

Comment: @doug -- I should be more careful about what I say. I haven't been paying attention lately, so I'm not up on the C++20 changes.

Comment: `atomic` is meant more for threads than ISRs, and it's a little awkward here: without it, you don't get a guarantee that the load in `loop` happens in a single uninterruptible instruction, but with it, the increment in `isr` will use a more expensive atomic RMW that isn't necessary.  I think in this situation, one would more commonly just use `volatile int x;` and trust the compiler to be sensible and generate a single-instruction load in `loop`.

Comment: You also want to be careful with `atomic`: for fancier types where no atomic load/store/RMW instructions exist, `atomic` may try to protect the object with a mutex lock.  Those may not be supported at all on your embedded system, and are not what you want here: if the interrupt fires while the main code holds the lock, you will deadlock.  So check `std::atomic_is_lock_free<T>`.

Comment: As always when doing c++ with embedded systems, be very familiar with the compiler/hardware as there are often limitations you need to be aware of. I've saved a lot of time examining the generated op codes doing things like this. OTOH, things have gotten a lot better after c++98. That said, if `x` is `std::atomic<int>`, and it compiles,  `x++` should be expected to work.